# C++ Shader matrix question

Tags: c++, matrix, glsl, shader, hlsl

While examining shader examples I recently found that it's pretty often
to pass the **world inverse transpose** matrix with the *world* and *world-view-projection*
matrices.

```
float4x4 worldMatrix;
float4x4 worldViewProjectionMatrix;
float4x4 worldInverseTransposeMatrix;
```

*Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the purpose of that and where it can be used. Could someone explain that?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The world inverse transpose matrix is often used for transforming normals into viewspace.